# cycle month transaction based on contract start date SQL

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I am having a data structured as dates and transactions along with the start date of the client contract, I want to show the data monthly but the start day of the month should be based on the contract start date.

for example if the contract starts 10th of the December then December should sum number of transactions between 10th of December to 9th of Jan.

Comment: Maybe to show example data and output needed ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show your code so far? Also, as igr says, have you got example data?